# SQL Date transformations

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-insert, transformation

I've received data in Excel and the DATE column (named ALL_PERIODS) is STRING and has this format:

> JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14

January, February, March 2014, Week end 04/05/14

I need to divide this column into three new columns: DATE_ (DATE), YEAR_ (INT), QUARTER_ (INT), so I've written these transformations:

Column DATE:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
   ADD DATE_TEMP VARCHAR2 (128);
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_TEMP = SUBSTR(ALL_PERIODS, -2, 2);
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_TEMP = REPLACE(DATE_TEMP, '/',  '');
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_TEMP = to_char(to_date(DATE_TEMP, 'mmddyyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_TEMP = REPLACE(DATE_TEMP, '00',  '20');
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_TEMP = TO_DATE(DATE_TEMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
ADD DATE_ DATE;
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
   SET DATE_ = DATE_TEMP;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
   DROP COLUMN DATE_TEMP;
```

Column YEAR:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
    ADD YEAR_TEMP VARCHAR2(128 BYTE);
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET YEAR_TEMP =  SUBSTR(ALL_PERIODS, 8, 4);
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
    ADD YEAR_ NUMBER(4);
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET YEAR_ =  YEAR_TEMP;
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET YEAR_ = CONCAT('20', YEAR_);
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
    DROP COLUMN YEAR_TEMP;
```

Column Quarter:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
    ADD QUARTER NUMBER(1);
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET QUARTER_ = 4
        WHERE DATE_ = '30-DEC-17';
...and the same with other 3 quarters
```

It somehow works, but I guess it is not effective (I'm not very advanced in SQL and I'm still learning), and **the update operations are too slow, so I'd like to transform the ALL_PERIODS column while inserting the data into new table with the three needed columns.**

Could you please tell me, how should the INSERT look like?
Thank you
N.

Comment: How do you distinguish June and July from January?

Comment: The data are distributed quarterly, it's always JFM, AMJ, JAS or OND. But the months aren't important for my analysis. I need the quarters (as integer or number).

Comment: That could be handled with a simple `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started off with simply inserting records to emulate your Excel date string. You can use this logic to see how the transformations can be done.

> **SETUP**
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO myTable (baseDate)
> SELECT 'JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'AMJ 14 - W/E 06/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'JAS 14 - W/E 09/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'OND 14 - W/E 12/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'JFM 15 - W/E 04/05/15' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'AMJ 15 - W/E 06/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'JAS 15 - W/E 09/05/14' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'JAS 49 - W/E 03/05/49' FROM dual
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT 'JAS 50 - W/E 04/05/50' FROM dual
> ```

This next `SELECT` row verifies the default date format for your server. This value could affect the date interpretations of your string.

> ```
> SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
> ```
>
> ```
> | VALUE     |
> | :-------- |
> | DD-MON-RR |
> ```

After I have the values inserted, I can just update my table based on that value.

> ```
> UPDATE myTable
> SET
>     DATE_ = 
>         TO_DATE(
>             SUBSTR(baseDate,INSTR(baseDate, ' ', -1)+1,8) -- Find last space to get end of string date value.
>             , 'MM/DD/RR'
>         )  /* TO_DATE already creates date object. RR mask rounds to 4-digit year. (49 = 1949, 50 = 2050) */
>     , QUARTER_ = 
>         CASE SUBSTR(baseDate, 1, 3)
>             WHEN 'JFM' THEN 1 
>             WHEN 'AMJ' THEN 2
>             WHEN 'JAS' THEN 3
>             WHEN 'OND' THEN 4
>         END
> ```

For `DATE_`, you don't need to do a `TO_CHAR` since `TO_DATE` will convert your string to a date value for the date column in the db. Your database doesn't really care if a date looks like 'yyyy-mm-dd', because it doesn't see it that way anyway. I used the `RR` mask to convert the 2-digit year value to a 4-digit year value. This will translate `49` AS `2049` and `50` as `1950`. If you don't have any need for `19xx` dates, you can just use `YY`. If you need to, you can do additional validation on your string value to ensure it can be converted to a date.

For `QUARTER_`, it's just a simple `CASE` statement to interpret your quarter string to a number.

Then, I update `YEAR_` based off of the date value in `DATE_`. This ensures that my year stays consistent within the row. It can also be done up in the initial update if the value is extracted from the base string.

> ```
> UPDATE myTable
> SET YEAR_ = EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM DATE_ )
> ```

This gives us:

> ```
> BASEDATE              | DATE_     | YEAR_ | QUARTER_
> :-------------------- | :-------- | ----: | -------:
> JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14 | 05-APR-14 |  2014 |        1
> AMJ 14 - W/E 06/05/14 | 05-JUN-14 |  2014 |        2
> JAS 14 - W/E 09/05/14 | 05-SEP-14 |  2014 |        3
> OND 14 - W/E 12/05/14 | 05-DEC-14 |  2014 |        4
> JFM 15 - W/E 04/05/15 | 05-APR-15 |  2015 |        1
> AMJ 15 - W/E 06/05/14 | 05-JUN-14 |  2014 |        2
> JAS 15 - W/E 09/05/14 | 05-SEP-14 |  2014 |        3
> JAS 49 - W/E 03/05/49 | 05-MAR-49 |  2049 |        3
> JAS 50 - W/E 04/05/50 | 05-APR-50 |  1950 |        3
> ```

Since `DATE_` is an actual date object, on display, you can format it with whatever mask you want.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=692e6e984cd591f1535b8bd39b35282c)*

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (COL1, COL2, ... DATE_, QUARTER_, YEAR_)
SELECT sr.COL1, sr.COL2, .... 
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(sr.ALL_PERIODS, -8), 'mm/dd/yy'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') DATE_,
CASE SUBSTR(sr.ALL_PERIODS, 1, 3)
WHEN 'JFM' THEN 1 
WHEN 'AMJ' THEN 2
WHEN 'JAS' THEN 3
WHEN 'OND' THEN 4
END QUARTER_,
'20'||SUBSTR(sr.ALL_PERIODS, 5,2) YEAR_,
FROM SOURCE_TABLE sr
[WHERE sr.COL99 = 'Y'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The DDL-Statements (add/delete column) are slow and unnecessary. You should not change the table definition when inserting data!

I would insert the 3 columns like this (replace the date string i used with the real ALL_PERIODS value):

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (DATE_, YEAR_, QUARTER_)
TO_DATE(SUBSTR('JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14', -8), 'dd/mm/yy'),
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(SUBSTR('JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14', -2), 'yy')),
-- OR SHORTER IF ALWAYS IN THE 2000: TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14', -2)) + 2000
DECODE(SUBSTR('JFM 14 - W/E 04/05/14',1,3), 'JFM', 1, 'AMJ', 2, 'JAS', 3, 'OND', 4);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If ALL_PERIODS is already loaded into the table?
And the extra columns to calculate are already added to the table?

Then 1 update should suffice.

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET 
 DATE_ = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(RTRIM(ALL_PERIODS),-8),'MM/DD/YY')
,YEAR_ = 2000+SUBSTR(ALL_PERIODS,5,2)
,QUARTER_ = DECODE(SUBSTR(ALL_PERIODS,1,3), 'JFM', 1, 'AMJ', 2, 'JAS', 3, 'OND', 4)
WHERE ALL_PERIODS IS NOT NULL 
  AND DATE_ IS NULL
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee4faccfa6854861cfcba4e780b75509)*